# How to combine iron-timer and moment-js to show hh:mm:ss format in polymer

Tags: polymer

I'm trying to convert the time I use in a timer to hh:mm:ss format using moment js but getting stuck. Below is my code.

```
<iron-timer id="timer" start-time="150" end-time="0" current-time="[[currentTime]]">
<moment-js date="[[_calculatedTime(currentTime)]]"></moment-js>
</iron-timer>
```

So when the time starts the time doesn't update in case of a formatted date. How can I get this to work

Comment: That doesn't look like syntactically correct code/markup (the moment-js part). Also, you seem to be using one-way binding for `currentTime` so you won't be notified about changes. Using curly brackets for the binding, I can imagine that `<iron-timer id="timer" start-time="150" end-time="0" current-time="{{currentTime}}"></iron-timer>` could already solve your problem. Other than that, look here for format options: http://saeidzebardast.github.io/moment-js/components/moment-js/

Comment: but how can I convert seconds to hh:mm:ss format? what ever I use only seems to update the hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with, but your question is somewhat incomplete, so correct me if I'm going a wrong way.

Component dependencies: polymer 2.5, iron-timer 2.1.2, moment-js 0.7.2

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Timer</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-timer/iron-timer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/moment-js/moment-js.html">
</head>
<body>
<dom-module id="moment-timer">
  <template>
    <iron-timer id="timer" start-time="150" end-time="0" current-time="{{currentTime}}"></iron-timer>
    <moment-js date="[[_toMilliSecs(currentTime)]]" format="HH:mm:ss" utc></moment-js>
  </template>
  <script>
    class MomentTimer extends Polymer.Element{
      static get is(){
        return 'moment-timer';
      }
      static get properties(){
        return {
          currentTime: Number
        }
      }
      _toMilliSecs(currentTime){
        return currentTime * 1000;
      }
      ready(){
        super.ready();
        this.$.timer.start();
      }
    }
    window.customElements.define(MomentTimer.is,MomentTimer);
  </script>
</dom-module>
<moment-timer></moment-timer>
</body>
</html>
```

There are a few things to note:

1. You have to start the timer somewhere in your script. I did this in the ready() callback. Make sure to call `super.ready()` first.
2. You need to pass the `currentTime` property as milliseconds to the `moment-js` element - I use a method `_toMilliSecs` to do just that.
3. As shown in one of the demo-examples from moment-js, you need to set the `utc` property on the `moment-js` element. This is necessary to give a starting  reference for your count-down. Essentially, we have it calculate the time from 1970-01-01 00:00:00 and set the timer relative to that. The effect is the same.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yeah, you nailed it. I missed the utc, and the conversion to milliseconds.